# oledbCnn not connecting to Access Database

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to connect to a database. When I do a simple Select * it works, but the moment I add a WHERE clause it no longer properly works and says it cannot connect. The column name is correct, and I'm sure there is a last name of Lee in the database. Why would this work during a simple select and not when there is a where clause?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim oledbCnn As OleDbConnection
    Dim oledbAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sql As String
    Dim i As Integer

    connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=S:\Reporting Database.mdb;"
    sql = "SELECT * FROM [extract1] WHERE [extract1].[PI First Name] = Lee"
    oledbCnn = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)
    Try
        oledbCnn.Open()
        oledbAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oledbCnn)
        oledbAdapter.Fill(ds)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        oledbAdapter.Dispose()
        oledbCnn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Should Lee not be between quotes?

Comment: You're correct. Sorry about that. Sometimes its so easy to overlook the simple stuff

Comment: @L-Three correct, but Single Quotes to be precise. Also instead of using dynamic select statements use OleDbParameters, Dynamic string just expose to many security and safety risks to your database.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you should put `Lee` between quotes, like:

```
 sql = "SELECT * FROM [extract1] WHERE [extract1].[PI First Name] = 'Lee'"
```

Hint: use [parameters](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06) to avoid sql injection.